# Is it worth Parallel/Concurrent INSERT INTO... (SELECT...) to the same Table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, plpgsql

I was attempting an **INSERT INTO.... ( **SELECT...** )** (inserting a batch of rows from SELECT... subquery), onto the same table in my database. For the most part it was working, however, I did see a "Deadlock" exception logged every now and then. Does it make sense to do this or is there a way to avoid a deadlock scenario? On a high-level, my queries both resemble this structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myConcurrentProc() LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  LOOP
     EXIT WHEN row_count = 0

     WITH cte AS (SELECT *
     FROM TableA tbla
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB tblb WHERE tblb.id = tbla.id)
     INSERT INTO concurrent_table (SELECT id FROM cte);

     COMMIT;

     UPDATE log_tbl
     SET status = 'FINISHED',
     WHERE job_name = 'tblA_and_B_job';

  END LOOP;
END
$procedure$;
```

And the other script that runs in parallel and **INSERTS...** also to the same table is also basically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myConcurrentProc() LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  LOOP
     EXIT WHEN row_count = 0

     WITH cte AS (SELECT *
     FROM TableC c
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableD d WHERE d.id = tblc.id)
     INSERT INTO concurrent_table (SELECT id FROM cte);

     COMMIT;

     UPDATE log_tbl
     SET status = 'FINISHED',
     WHERE job_name = 'tbl_C_and_D_job';

  END LOOP;
END
$procedure$;
```

So you can see ***I'm querying two different tables*** in each script, however inserting into the same `some_table`. I also have the **UPDATE...** statement that writes to a log table so I suppose that could also cause issues. Is there any way to use **BEGIN... END** here and **COMMIT** to avoid any deadlock/concurrency issues or should I just create a 2nd table to hold the "tbl_C_and_D_job" data?

Comment: In the log file there should be extensive information about what actually caused the deadlock.  Please post that.

Comment: Your example code is not syntactically valid, for multiple reasons.  That makes it hard to know what your real code does.